# Word for misusability

Tags: single-word-requests, software

I'm trying to articulate a question on stackoverflow. In the question, I state that I'm designing an API, and I want to **minimize "misusability"** within that API. "Misusability" is not a word, as far as I know, so I'm asking whether there is another word that can communicate something along the lines of "misusable" or "not misusable".

Comment: "minimize the chance/likelihood of misuse"?

Comment: or "minimize the scope for misuse"

Comment: [Pervertible is a word](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pervertible); so *pervertibility* should be - dictionary.reference.com [has it](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pervert). It has sexual/moral connotations though that might not be desirable. That's the best I can come up with a for single word.

Comment: I might use the phrase "susceptibility to misuse."

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *misapplication* or *misapplicability* will work for you.

> [**misapplication**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/misapplication) *noun*: incorrect or improper use. "this silly gossiping is a serious *misapplication* of your time." (Merriam-Webster *online*)

Comment: I think *misapplication* is just synonymous with *misuse* and would still require words to indicate the ability to be misapplied (so *misuse* would be better). To include the ability the answer would need to be *misapplicability* but that sounds like the opposite of *applicability*, which is more about the API being unsuitable than misused.

Comment: @LittleEva Avon is right. I'm not looking for a synonym for misuse, but a way to describe the tendency or ability to be misused.

Comment: Something like, *misapply*? Some situation where something is applied inappropriately?

Comment: The ability of it to be misapplied/misused if I understand correctly.